# PDO Exception after moving to new host

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, drupal-7

We were developing website in Drupal 7 for some time, it was running on few different machines/servers and all went well until we deployed it to live server (shared hosting).

Most of the time it's running well on live too, but sometime it just shoots this error message:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in db_delete() (line 2484 of /is/htdocs/wp10970389_C2CBFVDOLQ/www/drupal7/includes/database/database.inc).
Additional
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in locale() (line 720 of /is/htdocs/wp10970389_C2CBFVDOLQ/www/drupal7/modules/locale/locale.module).
Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in db_merge() (line 2448 of /is/htdocs/wp10970389_C2CBFVDOLQ/www/drupal7/includes/database/database.inc).
Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in db_delete() (line 2484 of /is/htdocs/wp10970389_C2CBFVDOLQ/www/drupal7/includes/database/database.inc).
```

It gives that error when we are clearing the cache. Not every time, but in i.e. 70% of tries. In other 30% cache clearing runs well.

This also happens when I try to install new module (I guess cache clearing is done in that case too) and installation fails. I see module as installed, but it's admin page doesn't exist (works well on staging).

Any idea what can cause this error?

Comment: Are you using a hostname for the database connection? (e.g. db.host.com)

Comment: Yes, tried "localhost", "127.0.0.1", real host address. They all work most of the time, but when clearing the cache they shoot that message, "full screen".

Comment: It sounds like somewhere is using a different hostname. That error means that the DNS couldn't be looked up for that domain.

Comment: Hmm...it is multi domain site. We are using "Domain access" module for that. But what I said goes for a single domain. Most of the time it works well - that's what confuses me the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

So problem was that I had Drupal migrate module and it was configured to use second database (Drupal 6, from old site) on my VM only. On staging that second DB configurations was also wrong, but for some reason (I guess different PHP settings) it was not shooting that error. On live it was.

And what I didn't know is that Drupal migrate module is connecting that second DB even if it's not used directly, i.e. when cache is cleared - have no idea why.